# optimizing Enemy generator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have created a script for generating enemies at the scene. It is a wave based enemy generator, a group of enemies get generated then it waits until all of them are dead and then goes to the next round. Here is the code:

```
while (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player") != null)
    {
        Spawner();
        if (waveCount == 1)
        {
            sound.clip = startRoundAlert;
            sound.Play();
            Instantiate(enemyz[0], SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
            waveCount++;

        }
        else if (waveCount == 2)
        {
            if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length == 0)
            {
                sound.clip = endRoundAlert;
                sound.Play();
                roundText.text = "Get ready for round" + waveCount;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
                roundText.text = "";

                sound.clip = startRoundAlert;
                sound.Play();

                Instantiate(enemyz[0], SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
                Spawner();
                Instantiate(enemyz[0], SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                waveCount++;

            }
        }
        else if (waveCount == 3)
        {
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length == 0)
            {
                sound.clip = endRoundAlert;
                sound.Play();
                roundText.text = "Get ready for round" + waveCount;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
                roundText.text = "";

                sound.clip = startRoundAlert;
                sound.Play();

                Instantiate(enemyz[1], SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                waveCount++;

            } 
        }
```

This script works correctly but after checking with unity profiler I think it is not optimized enough. If anyone has a suggestion for making it better I would be really happy to hear it.

Comment: Since your code works, this would be a great question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: "checking with unity profiler I think it is not optimized enough"
Why do you think so? Explain what results are dislikable or what is bad about your script. Is it the execution time?

Comment: with this script the frame rate is about 650 (it's a mobile game) without it suddenly it goes up to about 770 - 800.

Comment: When does it suddenly go up? at what point? A specific round? after a specific amount of time?

Comment: without this code at start frame rate is 800 and with it (before spawning the enemies) it is between 650 to 700. and thanks for the code!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I tried to clean up your game loop a bit - but really your code would cut out early anyway because you have the Enemy check before doing any work - so I think this is really more just a cleaning up of the code.

I think to really help you with performance, we'd need to see some of the other methods - and it would be great if you could say why you think it's not optimized

```
while(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player") != null)
{
    Spawner(); //What does this do?
    if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length == 0)
    {
        StartNextRound();
        waveCount++;
    }
}

private void StartNextRound()
{
    switch(waveCount) 
    {
        case 1:
            Instantiate(enemyz[0], SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 2:
            NewRoundSetup()
            Instantiate(enemyz[0], SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
            Spawner();
            Instantiate(enemyz[0], SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 3:
            NewRoundSetup()
            Instantiate(enemyz[1], SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
            break;
    }
}

private void NewRoundSetup() 
{
    sound.clip = endRoundAlert;
    sound.Play();
    roundText.text = "Get ready for round" + waveCount;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
    roundText.text = "";

    sound.clip = startRoundAlert;
    sound.Play();
}
```